# Installing an older version of powerdns on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt

I need to install pdns-server and pdns-backend-mysql 3.4.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.
If I use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install pdns-backend-mysql
```

then version 4 will be installed. I need version 3.4.5

Also this also won't work:

```
sudo apt-get install pdns-backend-mysql=3.4.5
```

(other combinations such as 3.4.5-1build2_amd64 also don't work).

I can find the package here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/pdns-backend-mysql/3.4.5-1build2

But if I download it and use `dpkg -i` to install it with `apt-get -f install`, then it would still install version 4.

```
Unpacking pdns-backend-mysql (4.0.3-1pdns.xenial) over (3.4.5-1build2)
```

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: Use older Ubuntu 14.04 instead, which runs pdns 3.3?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: There's **no easy** way to run non-16.04 packages on a 16.04 system when they disrupt other elements of your system. You want something that packages cannot provide. Choose the complexity that is least painful to you: 14.04 in a VM, or compile from source yourself.